# Adding 'overflow: auto' to SVG does not give it scroll bars

Tags: html, css, svg

According to this [MDN Web Docs Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow), the overflow property should work with SVGs the same way it does in regular HTML/CSS. However, neither does it doesn't work for me nor on the example given on the very same MDN page.

So how do I go about adding scroll bars to an SVG that is larger than the specified width?

PS: I have attached the MDN example to this post in the following snippet

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" overflow="auto">
  <text y="20">This text is wider than the SVG, so there should be a scrollbar shown.</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179418/horizontal-scrolling-in-svg

Answer (score 0):

On the MDN web docs you linked to, you can also read :

> The `overflow` attribute sets what to do when an element's content is
> too big to fit in its block formatting context. **This feature is not
> widely implemented yet.**
>  [[source MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow)

So unfortunatly, this won't work on any browser yet as specified in [the browser compatibility chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow#browser_compatibility).

**Workaround :**
For your example, the easiest is to use a normal HTML markup like this :

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This text is wider than the SVG, so there should be a scrollbar shown.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the compatibility issue. 

But I'm trying to make the SVG have drag-to-scroll so I needed the SVG to have scroll bars. So a normal HTML approach wouldn't work for me

Comment: It doesn't work on SVG

Comment: @Gnopor thats is exaclty what this answer states : scollbars on SVG elements aren't supported  by browsers yet. Therefore, and html approach is required if you need the scrollbars.

Comment: Ok je vois. But the answer isn't ok (I think) as it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @Gnopor that is your call. I believe it does answer the question as it explains why you can't have scrollbars on svg elements and it gives a workaround. Ok that workaround doesn't work for all use cases but now (may 22) it is the best you can do.

Comment: indeed. I have used your workaround and it works like you have explained but I didn't say that  it doesn't work at all. I said only on SVG element.